# EF Core with Oracle 11g. Problem with IDENTITY PK

Tags: c#, oracle, ef-core-2.2

The project is runnig with .Net Core 2.2, EF Core and SQL Server. Now, I need to use this same projetc with Oracle 11g. I create a new Migration project with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core. The migration file generated is below:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AREAATUACAO",
                schema: "SISDETEC",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Oracle:ValueGenerationStrategy", OracleValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    DATACADASTRO = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    DATAATUALIZACAO = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    NOME = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AREAATUACAO", x => x.ID);
                });
```

And the script generated is:

```sql
BEGIN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE 
"SISDETEC"."AREAATUACAO" (
    "ID" NUMBER(19) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "DATACADASTRO" TIMESTAMP(7) NOT NULL,
    "DATAATUALIZACAO" TIMESTAMP(7) NOT NULL,
    "NOME" NVARCHAR2(2000),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AREAATUACAO" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)';
END;
```

But, in the Oracle 11g do not exists the IDENTITY command. The PKs must be generated with a trigger and a sequence.

How can I config de EF Core to generate commands for Oracle version 11g?

Comment: [SOLVED] Using UseOracleSQLCompatibility() extension. Link to documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreAPI.html#GUID-770CD8EA-F963-48A5-A679-CAF471A4DB1A

Comment: Please refrain from adding "SOLVED" and similar language to the title.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question  Instead, answer your question below.

Answer (score 2):

from https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreAPI.html#GUID-770CD8EA-F963-48A5-A679-CAF471A4DB1A

> Customers using Oracle Database version 11.2 should set `UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11")`

```
optionsBuilder.UseOracle("User Id=hr;Password=<password>;Data Source = inst1", b =>
  b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));
```